# O código abaixo calcula total emprestado p/cada vendedor mas está estourando a exceção ValueError devido a erro no conjunto

Tags: python, string, float

```
def valor_total_emprestimo(valor: float, quantidade: int) -> float:
      return valor * quantidade
    
    emprestimos = []
    
    try:
      with open(file='./credito.csv', mode='r', encoding='utf8') as fp:
        fp.readline() # cabeçalho
        linha = fp.readline()
        while linha:
          linha_emprestimo = {}
          linha_elementos = linha.strip().split(sep=',')
          #linha_elementos = linha.strip().split(sep=' ')
          linha_emprestimo['id_vendedor'] = linha_elementos[0]
          linha_emprestimo['valor_emprestimos'] =float(linha_elementos[1])
          linha_emprestimo['quantidade_emprestimos'] = int(linha_elementos[2])
          linha_emprestimo['data'] = linha_elementos[3]
          emprestimos.append(linha_emprestimo)
          linha = fp.readline()
    except ValueError:
    
      emprestimos_total = []
    
      for emprestimo in emprestimos:
            valor_total = valor_total_emprestimo(valor=emprestimo['valor_emprestimos'], quantidade=emprestimo['quantidade_emprestimos'])
            emprestimos_total.append({emprestimo['id_vendedor']: valor_total})
        
    for emprestimo_total in emprestimos_total:
      print(emprestimo_total)
```

Comment: Bom, de acordo com a sua pergunta, existe no seu arquivo CSV um valor com aspas. Você está tratando isso no código antes de converter para float?

Comment: Um dos números está entre aspas: `"4151.0"`, aí dá erro ao converter para `float`. Ou vc corrige no arquivo (deixa tudo sem aspas), ou remove na hora de converter: `float(linha_elementos[1].replace('"', ''))` - Dito isso, por que não usar o [módulo `csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)? Ele é mais adequado para ler CSV e trata as aspas. Além disso, dá pra computar as duas listas simultaneamente: https://replit.com/@hkotsubo/ReadCsvComputeTotals#main.py

Comment: Não relacionado ao problema, mas float e dinheiro geralmente não formam um bom par. Se for pra alguma estatística ou aproximação, ok, mas se precisa de exatidão, tem o [Decimal](https://docs.python.org/3/library/decimal.html) para isso.

Answer (score 1):

Como deve ter percebido, o erro que ocorre é:

> ValueError: could not convert string to float: '"4151.0"'

Isto é, o erro indica que o valor, com aspas, não pode ser convertido para `float`, justamente porque possui aspas. Você precisaria tratar o caso de existir as aspas removendo-as antes da conversão.

Porém, há uma solução melhor.

Como o que você basicamente está fazendo é ler um arquivo CSV e gerar um dicionário para cada linha, você pode utilizar as ferramentas que tem disponível no módulo `csv`, nativo do Python. Nele há uma classe chamada `DictReader` que processa um arquivo CSV e já te retorna um dicionário, considerando a primeira linha do arquivo como sendo o nome dos campos:

```py
import csv

with open(file='./credito.csv', mode='r', encoding='utf8') as fp:
    reader = csv.DictReader(fp)
    for row in reader:
        print(row)
```

O retorno seria, para o seu exemplo:

```
{'id_vendedor': '104271', 'valor_emprestimos': '448.0', 'quantidade_emprestimos': '1', 'data': '20161208'}
{'id_vendedor': '21476', 'valor_emprestimos': '826.7', 'quantidade_emprestimos': '3', 'data': '20161208'}
{'id_vendedor': '87440', 'valor_emprestimos': '313.6', 'quantidade_emprestimos': '3', 'data': '20161208'}
{'id_vendedor': '15980', 'valor_emprestimos': '808.0', 'quantidade_emprestimos': '6', 'data': '20161208'}
{'id_vendedor': '215906', 'valor_emprestimos': '2212.0', 'quantidade_emprestimos': '5', 'data': '20161208'}
{'id_vendedor': '33696', 'valor_emprestimos': '2771.3', 'quantidade_emprestimos': '2', 'data': '20161208'}
{'id_vendedor': '33893', 'valor_emprestimos': '2240.0', 'quantidade_emprestimos': '3', 'data': '20161208'}
{'id_vendedor': '214946', 'valor_emprestimos': '4151.0', 'quantidade_emprestimos': '18', 'data': '20161208'}
{'id_vendedor': '123974', 'valor_emprestimos': '2021.95', 'quantidade_emprestimos': '2', 'data': '20161208'}
{'id_vendedor': '225870', 'valor_emprestimos': '4039.0', 'quantidade_emprestimos': '2', 'data': '20161208'}
```

Veja que a biblioteca é capaz inclusive de tratar as aspas como uma string e, então, você conseguiria fazer a conversão para `float` "sem medo" fazendo `float(row["valor_emprestimos"])`.

Comment: Muito Obrigado!!!!